# How can I add a border, or otherwise emphasize a 3d-styled button?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a set of three buttons labeled 1, 2 and 3 for a touchscreen application interface.

When the user clicks one, it should be "selected" and have some kind of obvious change that shows this.

When using a flat button style I can do this with a border, however it seems this does not apply to Buttons with the default/3d style.

I've noticed the backcolor can be set, however this only seems to apply plain colors, which generally looks pretty ugly.

Is there a way I can add something like a border or emphasize the "selected" 3d-styled button in another way? Is there a better control for this purpose that works well with touch screen interfaces?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A button cannot indicate a "selected" state, it can only have the focus.  Which is of no use in a touch screen app.

What you want is a CheckBox instead.  Which also supports looking like a button, set its Appearance property to Button.  You can further tinker with the way it looks by modifying the FlatStyle property.  By setting it to Popup for example it acquires a 3D-look when checked.

Comment: Radio buttons in this case, but that does work much better, thanks! I wasn't aware of the Appearance property

Answer (score 1):

Well, I was able to add an inset border using:

```
class BorderButton : Button
{
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPaint(e);

        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(new Pen(Color.Black, 6), this.DisplayRectangle);
    }
}
```

It seems however the paint event can't draw outside of the button's borders, so an outset one wouldn't be possible using this technique.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem and now always use a label instead.  This way you can catch the on_click or mousedown events and apply background colours or images as if it was a button.

Comment: Unless the user doesn't (or can't) use a mouse. Then you catch the "Application_Uninstalled" event.